# How to implement continuous/real time speech to text in ionic 3 for android platform

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to implement continuous speech to text in ionic 3.

1.I tried with cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-speechrecognition plugin in which I changed Showpartial= true. But still there is no change on my android platform's output.

2. Moreover I had reffered  https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin as well. but on SpeechRecognizer() I couldn't find any showPartial() method.

How can i get continuous speech to text with ionic 3 which should work in android Platform.
please let me know if anyone have some insights on this problem.

Comment: Sorry please correct SpeechRecognizer() with SpeechRecognition().